# When exporting to pdf/ppt, PowerBi embedded report export with current view changed the color of the chart

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, embedded

After I applied the report filter, I tried to export the report in current view mode, but the color of the chart was different between the original report and the report in current view.

Comment: Changing colors usually linked to theme configuration. make sure you use the same theme on your report and dashboard.

Comment: But I didn't apply any theme to the report configuration. @Dordi